# Annotate each curve with a value calculated in a Loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In this code below, I am having a loop which is going to read different text files based on my input data and then do some calculations. I am also plotting a function which is dependent on time. So If the length of the loop is 5, then I will have 5 different overlays in a single plot. Since each curve corresponds to a flowtime, I want to annotate each curve in the graph with the appropriate value of t1 that changes for every iteration in the loop. Ideally I want to have a line with an arrow pointing to each curve and having the appropriate annotation.

I would also like to update the legends automatically in the graph, ie. each curve in the graph should correspond to a particular value of t1. I have looked into some example, but am unable to get anything to work for my problem. I request the SO community to help me.

In this example code, I am providing three text files. So If the code is run, it will generate 3 overlays. Each annotation should correspond to a unique value of t1 that is calculated in the loop.

Update 1: I modified the code so that the legend is updated according to each value of t1 that is calculated in the loop. It was a trivial fix. I have still not been able to annotate each curve with the value of t1.

```
 # ... package imports ...
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate  import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import interpolate
import math
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate  import RectBivariateSpline
plt.ioff()

Uj = 0.944              
W = 30.48              
dj = 0.3048             
dj_length = (2*dj)      
Ho_bar = 44.607         
Ho_bar = (Ho_bar-(2*dj))
Ho = (Ho_bar*(1/W))
djo = 1.2192            
rho = 998              
D = W/W

path = "Location where the text files are located"
FT_init = 3.610
delt = 0.15
TS_init = 140

TS_init0 = 100

flowtime = np.linspace(50,2350,3)
timestep = ((flowtime-FT_init)/delt)+ TS_init
timestep = np.array(np.round(timestep,-2),dtype = 'int')

def Ekbar(KE_h,Y4):     
        plt.figure(1,figsize=(4.5,2.875))
        plt.plot(KE_h,Y4,label=(t1[s]))
        plt.ticklabel_format(style = 'sci', axis = 'x', scilimits=(0,0))
        plt.ylim(Y4.min(),Y4.max())
        plt.xlabel("X")
        plt.ylabel('Y')
        plt.tight_layout()

for s in range(len(timestep)):

        flowtime1 = flowtime
        flowtime1[s] = (timestep[s]-TS_init)*delt+FT_init 
        flowtime1[s] = np.array(np.round(flowtime[s]),dtype = 'int') 
        q = np.array(flowtime1)    
        timestepstring=str(timestep[s]).zfill(4)

        t = ((Uj*dj)/(W*W))*q           ## Nondimensional time
        t1 = np.round(t,decimals=2)
        fname = path+"ddn130AE-"+timestepstring+".txt"
        f10 = open(fname,'r')
        data = np.loadtxt(f10,skiprows=1)
        data = data[np.logical_not(data[:,11]== 0)]       

        data = data[data[:, 2].argsort()]
        Y  = data[:,2]          # Assigning Y to column 2 from the text file
        limitz = np.nonzero(Y==dj_length)[0][0]
        Vf = data[:,11]
        Vf = Vf[limitz:]
        Tr = data[:,9]          
        Tr = Tr[limitz:]       
        X  = data[:,1]        
        X = X[limitz:]        
        Y  = data[:,2]          
        Y = Y[limitz:]        
        U_bar  = data[:,3]      
        U_bar = U_bar[limitz:]        
        V_bar  = data[:,4]      
        V_bar = V_bar[limitz:] 
        U = (U_bar/Uj)         
        V = (V_bar/Uj) 
        limit = np.nonzero(Y==Y.max())[0][0]
        limit1 = np.nonzero(X==X.max())[0][0]
        Y1 = Y[limit]
        X1 = X[limit1]  

        nx = (5*(W/dj))
        ny = (5*(Y1/dj))
        pts = np.vstack((X, Y)).T
        U1 = np.vstack((U))
        V1 = np.vstack((V))
        # The new x and y coordinates for the grid
        x = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), nx)
        y = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), ny)
        r = np.meshgrid(y,x)[::-1]

        ipts = np.vstack(a.ravel() for a in r).T
        Uf = griddata(pts,U1,ipts,method='nearest')
        Vf = griddata(pts,V1,ipts,method='nearest')

        Uf1 = np.multiply(Uf,Uf)
        Vf1 = np.multiply(Vf,Vf)
        velsum = np.array(Uf1+Vf1)
        velsum = np.reshape(velsum,(len(x),len(y)))

        KE_int = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x,y,velsum)
        Sip1 = KE_int(x,y)

        axisx = np.linspace(0,D,num=len(Sip1))          
        KE_h = np.zeros(len(Sip1[0]))

        for i in range(len(Sip1[0])):
                KE_h[i] = integrate.simps(Sip1[:,i],axisx,axis=0)                

        KE_h1 = integrate.simps(Sip1,axisx,axis=0)

        Y4 = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y1,num=len(KE_h))   
        Y4 = Y4/W 
        Ekbar(KE_h,Y4)

plt.savefig('test.png',format = 'png', dpi=1200, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[Upload](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wlizpine2fvwvuk/AAAtvNmt5TVezvObE00sr6EJa?dl=0)

Comment: Would legend suffice for your purposes? In other words, are the arrows absolutely needed?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, ideally I would want have the arrows included if possible.  I  also want to see how the legends  can be included. Please guide me on either of the methods. I can then decide what will be the best for publishing it

Comment: Could some one please help me? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide either a simplified version of your problem or a sample input file?

Comment: @hashmuke The sample files are uploaded. Please click on the "Upload" link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still think this question should have been simplified with a small example code.

In order to add an annotation you need to know two positions,

1. A point on the curve that you are pointing to, and
2. A point inside the axis where you want to put the text

For instance you can use the horizontal peak points, and annotate them using a label similar to the legend label. Assume the text position to have the following x coordinates,

```
annot_txt_pose = [2.0e-2, 2.0e-2, 1.5e-2]
```

while the y coordinates are assumed to be the same as the annotation y coordinates. Then after each plot command, you can use the following code to annotate the curves

```
label_str = "%s"%t1[s]
# maximum x value annotation 
annot_idx = np.argmax(KE_h)
# annotation arrow tip position 
arrow_tip = KE_h[annot_idx],Y4[annot_idx]
# annotation text position 
text_pos = annot_txt_pose[s],Y4[annot_idx]
plt.plot(arrow_tip[0], arrow_tip[1], 'o')
ax.annotate(label_str, xy=arrow_tip, xytext=text_pos, arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
```

The figure window need to be expanded to clearly see the annotation. The result on the example files looks like this
[image]

Comment: I have accepted your answer. From next time, I will post a simple example code in the question. I apologize for the trouble. I have a small question. I want to set the font size of the annotation text and also I want the arrow to be thinner. Could you please let me know how I can do this as soon as possible. Thank you

Comment: You can find more examples for annotation in http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html. Regarding the font size just specify it as
`ax.annotate(label_str, xy=arrow_tip, xytext=text_pos, arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05), fontsize=10)`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really helped me. I did further search on annotation and managed to obtain what I wanted.